# Weird issue with BracketHighlighter

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed BracketHighlighter on a clean install of Sublime Text 3 (latest version) using a clean install of Package Control.  I also had the issue on a sublime text 2 install before.  Below I show the issue I am having where if I put the cursor (denoted with "|") on the ending element, tags (denoted by "T") will show for both, but if I put it for the beginning element, a question mark will appear.  Has anyone had this issue before?  How should I go about solving it?

```html
?1  <d|iv>
 2      <h1>Blah</h1>
 3  </div>

T5  <div>
 6      <h1>Blah</h1>
T7  </d|iv>
```

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

- No changes to the settings.  Other plugins installed are: AdvancedNewFile, OpenInBrowser, Package Control, BrowserRefresh, ViewInBrowser, and SublimeLinter
- This problem exists with all kinds of tags.

Comment: Please [edit] your post with a link to a screenshot of your issue, and someone with higher rep will link it into your question. Also, please post any changes you've made to the BracketHighlighter settings, as well as any other plugins you have installed. I cannot replicate this behavior in ST3. Do you see the same issue with the `<h1>` tags?

Comment: Edits made.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using your actual code, I was able to reproduce the issue with ST3. I'd suggest opening an [issue](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/issues) on the project's Github page, pointing to this question and including all the info you mentioned here. Also, BTW, you're missing an `=` in your `<label>` tag between `for` and `"fname"`.

Answer (score 0):

Filing an issue at the repo is correct response.  This issue should be patched now.  Details are found here: https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter/issues/205#issuecomment-64310671.